# Schedule A bi-weekly job to run at 5 PM on Friday

Tags: airflow

I saw 2 discussions on bi-weekly job. However, both don't have a precise solution to this technical requirement. That's why, I am starting this thread.

I have a requirement to run a DAG every alternate Friday at 5 PM. So, if I start my DAG on 19 Mar, 2021, then it should run on the 19th of Mar, 2021 and the subsequent runs should happen on alternate Fridays. This would mean that after 19th Mar, 2021 the next run should happen on 02 Apr, 2021. How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of deliberations and help from many in the community, I got the answer from AirFlow slack community.

```
def _skipcondition(execution_date, **_):
    first_valid_friday = datetime(2021, 4, 9)
    return (execution_date - first_valid_friday).days % 14 == 0
with DAG(dag_id='fortnightSchedule',default_args = default_args, schedule_interval = "0 17 * * 5", catchup=False) as dag:
    check_valid_friday = ShortCircuitOperator(
        task_id="check_if_correct_friday",
        python_callable=_skipcondition,
        provide_context=True,
        )
    rest_of_tasks = DummyOperator(
        task_id="dependent_dummy",
    )
check_valid_friday >> rest_of_tasks
```

Its a simple function that returns True when the number of days between execution date and first execution date is divisible by 14.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any straightforward way to do this, but I can provide some valid approaches by which you can do it.

**Option 1**

1. Set the schedule to `0 17 * * 5` - which translates to `At 17:00 on Friday`.
2. Use a [BranchPythonOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html?highlight=branch) to get the last dag successful branch run date from airflow variables and check if it is 14 days from the current run date.
3. The date will be stored as an airflow variable and updated only when the true branch (alternate Friday runs) succeed.
4. If yes, continue the rest of the DAG, else, skip the rest of the tasks. An example of how to implement this is given in the above-mentioned link.

**Option 2**

1. Set the schedule to something like `0 17 1,14 * 5` - which translates to `At 17:00 on day-of-month 1 and 14 and on Friday`. This will run twice a month.

***Note***: Option 1 is preferred over Option 2 as it will help tackle the requirement as expected.

Hope these help!

Comment: Jacob, Thanks for your response. I want some clarification on option 1. The schedule is set for every Friday. After the 1st run, the last DAG run will always be 7 days, isn't it? The 14 day check will never become true. How can the subsequent runs branch to the right task set?

Comment: @AnandRajakrishnan Good catch. You can write the last execution date to an airflow variable. This task will be placed at the end of the successful branch so that it will always have the last full run date. I have updated my answer with the same.

Comment: I think we have to use TaskInstance to get the last successful run date. However, I am unable to figure out its syntax.

Comment: @AnandRajakrishnan With option 1, you will have two branches. You should save today's execution date to an airflow variable. You can use the `{{ execution_date }}` macro to get the date. There are other macros available as well, which you can read about [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html)

Comment: I don't think that {{ execution_date }} is going to help. As the job runs every week, the execution_date will never be more than 7 day older.

Comment: @AnandRajakrishnan It will work as long as you only update the airflow variable which holds the last successful run date on alternate days. Your DAG will have that task only on days when it satisfies the 14-day condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use datetime.timedelta function.
you can execute DAG after 14days based on start_date.
using this you can execute DAG below day.

- 2021-03-19
- 2021-04-02
- 2021-04-16
- 2021-04-16
  ....

this can be the example.

```
import datetime

dag = Dag(
    dag_id="bi_weekly_dag",
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=14)
    start_date=datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=4, day=19)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't verify your answer as I left my organization last year :(